# Running ACI with SQL Server on premises

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have a container (linux .NET Core) running in Azure. This application reads from Azure Service Bus and writes information in a database on-premises.

The connection to ASB is working fine but when the application tries to connect to SQL Server, I get a timeout. Initially, I was running the container with no network setup (the 'None' option). Then I went to public and it now gives me an IP address.

My infrastructure team added this IP to our firewall but either Azure is trying to access it with a different IP address OR the connection never leaves the Docker environment.

ps.: I have an App Service running (.NET Core API) and it **does** connect to the same SQL Server (same IP address) correctly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the IP address that outgoing from the Azure container group is random from [Azure cloud IP list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519), you can not directly add its IP to the firewall. You can vote up this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/33417370-use-the-same-exposed-public-ip-for-outbound-traffi) for using the same exposed public IP for outbound traffic starting from the container group.

Currently, you could [deploy container instances into an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet), then the container could communicate with on-premises resources through a [VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) or [ExpressRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-introduction). For more details, you could see [enable containers to use Azure Virtual Network capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/container-networking-overview).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Nancy. That was really helpful.